# A PopUp image on React Grid

Tags: reactjs, grid, popup

how can i implemented a Modal Pop UP or simple pop Up or other.

i have a GridView in React see: [My Grid](https://codesandbox.io/s/rt-checkbox-hoc-tjkr0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

how can i add an additional column that triger pop up that contain an image ?

i have an idea, may be click or double clic on a row will triger pop up or an simple column

i am beginner in react

thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve using Cell in react Table. let take you want open modal when clicked on first_name column.

```
    function getColumns(data) {
      const columns = [];
      const sample = data[0];
      Object.keys(sample).forEach(key => {
        if (key !== "_id" && key !== "first_name") {
          columns.push({
            accessor: key,
            Header: key
          });
        } else if(key === "first_name"){
columns.push({
            accessor: key,
            Header: key
            Cell: (rowInfo) => {
               // call your modal toggle function here
               // rowInfo contains data of that row. console and see what you can pass that in your function.
            }
          });
}
      });
      return columns;
    }
```

Comment: thanks you, i have follow your instruction. i add Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <input type="button" value="Open" onClick={() => this.openModal()} />
        ) i have update also mySandbox

Comment: you have placed getColumns() function outside class so, this.openModal won't work there as this refers to block scope of that function. place get coumns inside class or pass 'this' as param in function.